# Issues connecting C# app to remote server with Non-Split Tunnel VPN

Tags: c#, .net, windows, httpwebrequest, vpn

I have C# (.Net 4.5) Winforms app communicates with a webserver hosted on the internet.

It works flawless, until I turn on the VPN, which is restrictive and does not support split tunneling.

It is reproducible only by following these steps:

1. Start the .Net app and make a HttpWebRequest to a server - this goes through as expected.
2. Connect the VPN client. The VPN is configured to route all traffic through the VPN (as opposed to "split tunnelling" for intranet resources)
3. After the VPN connects, the webrequest stops working in the .NET app. The .NET app starts getting a generic "Unable to connect to the remote server" on `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse`:

   ```
   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 
   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xxx.206:443 
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean 
   connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, 
   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at DNSCacheTest.Form1.SendWebRequest(String url)
   ```

Turning off VPN, the app starts working and requests go through again.

**If the VPN is already connected before the application is started, the problem does not occur.**

This applies to any public server, even https://www.google.com.

I kept a watch on `NetStat` log for all these scenarios and here's what I observed:

- If I leave the application running and turn VPN ON, the application still tries to connect using old Foreign Address, there by failing.
- If I restart the application with VPN ON, the application now connects with a different proxy foreign address, and works fine.

I create a new `WebRequest` each time. I tried all possible ways to force the application to use newer address each time, but was unable to do so.

Below are few of the things I tried and didn't work:

1. Flushed DNS Recovery Cache
2. Flushed  ARP Cache
3. Deleted Destination Cache
4. Tried multiple pings to server through the same .Net app instance.
5. Tried adding routes in route table for existing server IP routing to proxy server IP.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in .Net framework, which does not pickup the updated addresses.

To fix this, I added before submitting each request:

```
webRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
```

With this, the framework explicitly picks up the updated proxy settings from IE Network options.